# How to synchronize delayed scheduled tasks to execute them fairly (in order)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime, uwp, synchronization

I'm writing a method to schedule some tasks that need to be executed in the right order as they were created, with a fixed delay for each task.

Basically, I need to replicate this behavior (where **Mx** is a method call that schedules a task, and **Tx** its corresponding task):

> M1--M2--M3--M4--M5--M6...
>
> ------T1--T2--T3--T4--T5...

The point here is that this method is called very frequently (*not by me, so I can't control that*) and *I need to be able to skip its execution if it gets called with two arguments that "nullify" each other* (for example, if the last call was Foo("a"), then I get Foo("b") and Foo("a"), I want to be able to skip these last two calls, as they're useless). That's why I'm using a `Queue` instead of just scheduling a task directly from inside each method call.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// Semaphore to synchronize the queue access
private readonly SemaphoreSlim QueueSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

// Arguments queue
private readonly Queue<String> History = new Queue<String>();

// The last argument (needed to understand the useless calls)
private String _LastArgument;

protected void Foo(String arg)
{
    // Wait and add the argument to the queue
    QueueSemaphore.WaitAsync().ContinueWith(ts =>
    {
        History.Enqueue(arg);
        QueueSemaphore.Release();

        // Small delay (100ms are enough in this case)
        Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(td =>
        {
            // Wait again before accessing the queue
            QueueSemaphore.WaitAsync().ContinueWith(tf =>
            {
                // Edge case for the removed calls
                if (History.Count == 0) 
                {
                    QueueSemaphore.Release();
                    return;
                }     

                // Get the next argument and test it               
                String next = History.Dequeue();
                if (_LastArgument != null && 
                    History.Count > 0 && 
                    History.Peek().Equals(_LastArgument))
                {
                    // Useless calls detected, skip them
                    StatesHistory.Dequeue();
                    QueueSemaphore.Release();
                    return;
                }
                _LastArgument= next;
                SomeOtherMethodWithTheActualCode(next);
                QueueSemaphore.Release();
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness);
}
```

Now, I have two issues here:

1. From what I see in the documentation, the `TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness` flag will only *try* to keep the original order for the scheduled tasks, but it does not guarantee that they will be executed in the same order
2. I've heard many times that the `Task.Delay` method is not reliable, and that it should not be used for synchronization purposes. So, if for example a delay call actually takes 101ms and another one 99ms, or 98ms, that would probably mess the whole thing up.
3. Since this method will be executed on the UI thread, I'd like to avoid to block synchronously to avoid problems with the UI

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain that I understood you well but you may want to try asynchronous loop (below is some pseudocode):

adding items to queue:

```
async Task AddToQueueAsync(WorkItem item)
{
    await LockQueueAsync();
    queue.Add(item);
    UnlockQueue();
}
```

and taking items in the infinite loop:

```
async Task InfiniteLoopThatExecutesTasksOneByOne()
{
    while(true)
    {
        WorkItem item = null;
        await LockQueueAsync();
        item = InspectTheQueueAndSkipSomethingIfNeeded();
        UnlockQueue();
        if(item!=null)
        await DispatchItemToUIThread(item);
        await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
}
```

With a loop your items will always be ordered. As a downside you'll have some code that is infinitely working, so you'd need some kind of mechanism to suspend/resume it when needed. Also it does not cover your third concern and I can't currently think of any way to implement precise delay asynchronously.

As a side note: you can keep the last task you scheduled and attach your new task as previous tasks continuation. That way you'll also preserve order.

Comment: I don't need a "precise" delay (could be 100, 110, it doesn't matter), but I don't want an "unprecise" delay to cause its continuation to be scheduled before a continuation that was created before that one (as that would mess up the tasks order). Also, I don't want to have a continuous loop in the background, and I need the scheduled tasks to be executed each after a fixed delay after the method call that created that task (so that I can do that check on consecutive calls). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Sergio0694 These two points contradict each other imho. You can only get one of two: execute the method after a fixed delay after it was created OR preserve order. For example, lets assume that the N-th method that was scheduled took long time to complete. You can either wait for it to complete (thus preserving the order and violating time constraint) OR you can launch the next method (thus spending some fixed time but breaking the order). Or I totally miss something.

Comment: @Sergio0694 I've added this later to my answer, you can also create continuation chains using `ContinueWith` - it would preserve order (but yet again - no guarantees for time consumption)

Comment: As for your first comment, they don't contradict each other, my initial explanation of the problem probably wasn't as accurate as I hoped. Just look at the Mx/Tx chart in my question - you can just imagine the whole problem as "I want to transpose each method call 100ms ahead in time", and you can assume each method call executes instantly (it's a short synchronous method).

Comment: @Sergio0694 ok, got it. Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas then. I don't think of any other means to do it. You can try chaining tasks to infinite chain but it also does not provide anything like strong guarantees as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a lot easier to just keep a collection of the arguments:

```
public Task Execution { get; private set; } = StartAsync();

private List<string> _requests = new List<string>();
private string _currentRequest;

private async Task StartAsync()
{
  while (true)
  {
    if (_requests.Count != 0)
    {
      _currentRequest = _requests[0];
      _request.RemoveAt(0);
      SomeOtherMethodWithTheActualCode(_currentRequest); // TODO: error handling
      _currentRequest = null;
    }
    await Task.Delay(100);
  }
}

protected void Foo(String arg)
{
  var index = _requests.IndexOf(arg);
  if (index != -1)
    _requests.RemoveRange(index, _requests.Count - index);
  else if (arg == _currentRequest)
    _requests.Clear();
  _requests.Add(arg);
}
```

This code assumes the type is created (and `Foo` is called) from the UI thread.

Comment: Wait, I have two questions here. 1) I don't see any synchronization mechanism, so for example if Foo calls the `Clear` method on the list right before `StartAsync` calls _requests[0], there would be an exception there 2) The `StartAsync` method has a 100ms delay between each call, while that's not the requested behavior. I want to delay each task 100ms ahead of the original call to `Foo`, but the distance between each scheduled task should not be changed. Here instead it's always 100ms (while Foo could have been called multiple times in under than 100ms). Plus, I'd prefer to avoid a busy loop.

Comment: The UI thread is used as the synchronization mechanism. Since your time delay is variable, you should consider using Rx instead.